# error during DB sync of nova in openstack

Tags: mariadb, openstack, openstack-nova

pymysql.err.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'instances' already exists")

While populating database in nova installation im getting this error.We are using maria DB 10.5.5 but still this issue is not solved. please help to resolve this issue..

Comment: Which command do you have exactly used for the sync?

Comment: su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage db sync" nova

Comment: Was the nova_api db sync successful prior to the nova db? Is it a fresh install or does the db already contain data that needs to be preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like db tables are already created, If this is a fresh installation,try to delete the nova database and re-create it.